# (Java) Minesweeper clone not correctly revealing squares?

Tags: java, minesweeper

so basically I've been making a minesweeper clone in Java. I had it working perfectly until I added the game win and lose parts and the big opening print. Now when I run it some of the spots that are next to zero's don't get revealed, even though they should. I can't figure out where the bug is though. Here's my code:

```
/**
 * A program to play Scat Scout...
 */
import static java.lang.System.*; // so you can write out.println() instead of System.out.println()
import java.util.*;

class ScatScout {
  static final int boardSize = 10;
  static final Random rand = new Random();
  static final boolean SCAT = true;
  static final boolean CLEAR = false;
  static int clearCounter = 100;
  static boolean gameWon = false;
  static boolean gameLost = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[boardSize+2][boardSize+2]; // scat or no scat
    boolean[][] exposed = new boolean[boardSize+2][boardSize+2]; // showing or hidden
    int[][] counts = new int[boardSize+2][boardSize+2]; // number of neighbors with scat
    if (args.length > 0) {
      rand.setSeed(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
    System.out.println("comment explaining game");
    createScat(board); //initialize the board
    compareScat(board, counts); //find how many scat are next to each spot
    while(!gameWon&&!gameLost){ //keep going until game win or loss
      printBoard(board, counts, exposed);
      System.out.println("Enter two integers (row and column):");
      expose(input.nextInt()+1, input.nextInt()+1, board, exposed, counts);
      if (gameLost){
        for (int i = 1; i<= board.length-2; i++){
          for (int j = 1; j<= board.length-2; j++){
            if (!board[i][j]){
              exposed[i][j] = true;
            }
          }
        }    
        printBoard(board, counts, exposed);
        System.out.print("You stepped in it! Yucky!"); //game lose 
        break;
      }
      gameWon = true; //game is one if all blanks but the bombs are exposed
      for(int i = 1; i<= board.length-2; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<= board[0].length-2; j++){
          if(!exposed[i][j]&&!board[i][j]){
            gameWon=false; //otherwise continue loop
          }
        }
      }
      if (gameWon){
        System.out.print("You cleared the scat! Congrats!"); //game win message
        break;
      }
    }
    input.close();
  }

  public static void printBoard(boolean[][] board, int[][] counts, boolean[][] exposed){ //initialize board
   int numRows = counts.length;
   int numCols = counts[0].length;
   System.out.println("  0123456789"); //print the border
   for(int i=1; i<=numRows-2; i++){
     System.out.print(i-1 + " "); //border
     for(int j=1; j<=numCols-2; j++){
       if (exposed[i][j] == true){
       System.out.print(counts[i][j]); //print the scat near a spot if it's exposed
       }
      else{
         System.out.print("*"); //print unknown spot
       }
     }
     System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.print(i-1); //border
     System.out.println(" ");
   }
   System.out.println("  0123456789"); //border
  }

  public static void createScat(boolean[][] board){ //randomly seed scat into field
    for(int i=1; i<= board.length-2; i++){
      int x = rand.nextInt(board.length-3)+1;
      int y = rand.nextInt(board.length-3)+1;
      if(x!=0&&x!=11&&y!=0&&y!=11&&board[x][y]==CLEAR){
      board[x][y]=SCAT; //scat in this random spot
      }
    }
  }

  public static void compareScat(boolean[][] board, int[][] counts){ //checks #scat in surrounding spots
    int numRows = counts.length;
    int numCols = counts[0].length;
    for(int i=1; i<=numRows-2; i++){
      for(int j=1; j<=numCols-2; j++){
        for(int ii=i-1; ii<=i+1; ii++){
          for(int jj=j-1; jj<=j+1; jj++){
            if(board[ii][jj]==SCAT){ //this looks at all scat in all directions around the original spot
              counts[i][j]=counts[i][j]+1; //adds to the counter if scat found around it
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static void expose(int c, int r, boolean[][] board, boolean[][] exposed, int[][] counts) { //exposes chosen spot
    if (exposed[r][c]) return; // nothing to do
    if (board[r][c]== SCAT){
      gameLost=true; //lose game if choose a spot with scat
    }
    exposed[r][c] = true;   // expose any neighbors that have zero counts
    if (counts[r][c] > 0) return;
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
      for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
        int x = r+i;
        int y = c+j;
        if (!(i==1 && j==1) && x >= 1 && x < board.length-1 && y >= 1 && y < board[x].length-1) {
          if (counts[x][y] == 0) {
            expose(x, y, board, exposed, counts);
          }
          else {
            exposed[x][y] = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: You should check that the input (those 2 ints) cannot be greater than the board itself, cause otherwise you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: hmm, no I've never done that before. where would I want breakpoints in order to test this, and how would it work with the user input? for example, if I i break after taking the input but before using it would it just store it until needed? @SteveSmith

Comment: @Miles07 its ok to get a outofboundsexception, as long as its not happening when i input 0-9 i dont mind. the only problem really is the 0s not correctly exposing all the spots next to them (though they do expose some...)

Comment: Stepping through the code still runs the code in exactly the same way, but also allows you to examine the value of vars and see which lines are being run.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida yes, but you could catch it and then repeat inputting those integers^^

Comment: You will need to **recursively** reveal all the 0's if the neighboring square is a 0 until a non zero square is revealed. [MineSweeper](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~dmarino/ucf/bhcsi/asgn/adv/sol/MineSweeper.java)

Comment: Oh, thanks everyone, I realized what the problem was. I accidentally switched r and c in my
    expose
method. Thanks for the comments!